# dnsmasq: return default IP address if address cannot be resolved

Tags: dnsmasq

dnsmasq allows to return an IP address for all DNS request:

> address=/#/192.168.1.1

This will overwrite all requests.

But is there a way to return this address only if a query could not be resolved?

Example:

- does-not-exit-123.com => 192.168.1.1
- google.de => 1.2.3.4 //whatever the actual address is